# How can I determine a gas partial pressure knowing the flow?

Tags: experimental-physics, pressure

I have a vacuum chamber with a pressure 10<sup>-8</sup> Torr.
Then I open an Oxygen valve with a set flow of 2 sccm from a tank with a pressure of 2 bars. The pressure in the chamber decreases to 10<sup>-2</sup> Torr. What is the partial pressure of the Oxygen in the chamber?

Is it 10<sup>-6</sup> Torr or 10<sup>-2</sup> Torr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pressure increases, not decreases, to $10^{-2}$ Torr.  As there is (almost) nothing in the chamber except oxygen, it contributes all the pressure.  Note that $10^{-6}+10^{-8} \neq 10^{-2}$  The flow does not matter at all.